# Dynamic Array for Sort and Clear contents

Tags: vba, excel

I have made an array for M2:Tx - The x will vary dependent code prior to this.

What I would like to do is have a 'clear contents' function and 'sort' function for this array (m2:tx).

I am just struggling to make the array DYNAMIC. If anyone could help.

I believe it will be something along these lines:

```
k = sh.Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row 'This will give me the length. 

Dim TaskDates As Range
Dim StartCell  As Range 'First part of Array
Dim EndCell As Range 'End of Array
Set EndCell = Range("T" & 2 + k) 'maybe 2 or 3
Set StartCell = Range("M2")
Set TaskDates = Range(StartCell, EndCell) 'Dynamic Range
```

This will work i beleive, but is there a more succinct methodology.

Comment: would you mind taking your time to kindly give proper feedbacks to all your previous answers questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand the logic by which you are setting your range.

If you want the last row in the range that starts with M2 to be the same as the last occupied row in Column A, then. in general

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

So to set your range `M2:Tx` where `x` = `LastRow`

```
Set TaskDates = Range("M2", "T" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
```

To sort the range, decide how you want it sorted, then record a macro.

Comment: This answer looks more succinct than the one I used, and I will edit. 

My query with the resolution to sort is that the range need to be dynamic so if a new entry is added to column A it will be included in the sort macro.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
Sub MakeRange()
    Dim x As Long, MyDynamicRange As Range
    x = 123
    Set MyDynamicRange = Range("M2:T" & x)
    MsgBox MyDynamicRange.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

[image]